# Jsoup Element.text() intermittent?

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

In the following snippet of code:

```
  String linkHref = "";
  String linkText = "";
  Elements links = div.getElementsByTag("a");
  for (Element link : links) {
    linkHref = link.attr("href");
    linkText += link.text();              
    break;
  }
```

linkText is sometimes empty, **even when I can see clearly** on the WebView that **the link text is there**!

On the other hand, linkHref always ends up with the correct value.

What could possibly explain this seemingly intermittent behavior?

Is this a bug in Jsoup? Something else that I may be missing?

**Update**, answering @ BalusC's questions below: The Jsoup version is **jsoup-1.5.2** and div.html() says:

```
<div class="d2 dl"> 
 <a href="nextp.html" class="cO"><img src="images/no001.jpg" alt="" vspace="0" width="69" border="0" height="69" hspace="0" /></a> 
 <span class="bc">2.</span> 
 <a accesskey="2" href="nextp.html"> Subject line </a> 
</div> 
<p class="aG">Human resource policies are viewed as a valuable to understand the companies.</p> 
<div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What URL? What Jsoup version? What does `div.html()` say?

Comment: why the `break` instruction? why not using directly `links[0]`?

Comment: @manji Nice observation (+1). Are you sure the two forms are 100% equivalent?

Comment: @manji links[0] produces "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Elements". You probably meant **links.get(0)**, but this is still no good as it will produce IndexOutOfBoundException if Elements is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first link doesn't contain text at all. It contains an image. So Jsoup is doing its job perfectly fine.

You probably want to make use of the [`Element#hasText()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#hasText%28%29) first to check if the link has text.

```
if (link.hasText()) {
    linkText += link.text();
}
```

Comment: I ended up soloving the problem by replacing **links = div.getElementsByTag("a");** with **links = div.select("a[accesskey]");**  Thanks + 1 for suggesting div.html() as a debugging tool.